# Why is 'humeur' in French sometimes translated as 'ill-humor' in English

Tags: vocabulaire

This is from Proust:

> Donc Saint- Simon raconte que Maulevrier avait eu l’audace de tendre la main à ses fils. Vous savez, c’est ce Maulevrier dont il dit : « Jamais je ne vis dans cette épaisse bouteille que de l’humeur, de la grossièreté et des sottises.

"humeur" was translated by Moncrieff as 'ill-humor' but I doubt it's a mistranslation since the word is included in a list containing 'grossièreté' and 'sottises', roughly, 'rudeness and silliness'.  My question is not why the translation but why P didn't simply write 'mauvaise humeur'?  According to

[humeur](https://context.reverso.net/translation/french-english/humeur)

'humeur' is translated 3300 times as humor/humour and only 4 times as 'ill-humor' and at least two of those examples come from Proust and the other two might as well.

Comment: Compare "She's in one of her moods" or "He's in a state" :)

Answer (score 2):

The meaning is indeed *mauvaise humeur*. Proust left out the adjective with a stylistic ellipsis, similar to the one used in the expression *être d'une humeur*:

> [**Humeur** (TLFi)](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/humeur)
> [...]
> **II.**, **C.-** Disposition de caractère, état de réceptivité dans lequel se trouve une personne à un moment donné.
> [...]
> − P. ell. *Être d'une humeur !* Être de très mauvaise humeur. *− Oh! mais il est d'une humeur, ce soir !...* (H. Bataille, Maman Colibri, 1904, I, 13, p. 13).*− Votre patron est d'une humeur ! fait-elle en détournant aussitôt les yeux. Encore un après-midi gâché...* (Bernanos, Mauv. rêve,1948, p. 904).

Note that the main meaning of *humeur* is **mood**, and it is the one used here. It never translates to "humor" when this word relates to laugh, amusement. It can have the mood meaning in English but it is rare ([AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=humor): *I'm in no humor to argue*). *Humeur*/humor also share their original meaning: a liquid, a body fluid (cognates with *humid*).

Comment: cool, thanks for that.

Comment: Dans la langue parlée « Il est d'une humeur. » n'est pas compréhensible  si une emphase et une intonation spéciale ne sont pas utilisées.

Comment: @LPH C'est exact mais un peu hors sujet.

Comment: I guess this is similar in English (and probably French): "I'm going to have words with you," where the implication is "confrontational words"

Answer (score 0):

Technically, Proust didn’t leave out “mauvaise” rather Saint Simon did and Proust or Swann is just quoting it. Saint Simon was writing his private thoughts in a journal which explains the colloquial tongue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Il y a une source ?